# Getting latest distinct values on a table using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with multiples different user options (key with some value). And I want to recover the latest values the user have selected in all keys. The idea is to show on the UI the latest selected options from the user. Note that the options are for different entities, that means that can be repeated on database.

For example:

```
1970-01-01
Key1 -> A
Key2 -> B


1970-01-02
Key1 -> C
Key3 -> D
```

The result of the latest options must be:

```
Key1 -> C
Key2 -> B
Key3 -> D
```

I think that I can do something like:

```
List<Property> findDistinctKeyByUser(String user);
```

That gives me all distinct properties from the users, but is not ensuring that the result only contains the latest ones. How can achieve this? Is it possible to achieve it using only JPA?